# I don't understand why Select-String isn't matching this

Tags: regex, powershell-2.0

```
$lines = '<string>D:\home\bob\utility.mdb</string>'

[String[]]$varr = $lines | Select-String -AllMatches -Pattern "<string>*.mdb" |
Select-Object -ExpandProperty Matches |
Select-Object -ExpandProperty Value
```

This is returning null.

Ultimately I want the entire line, from the `<string>` to the `</string>`.

But apparently I don't know how to express this in powershell.

Comment: Do you perhaps mean `\S` instead of `\s` for the first `\s`?

Comment: I've removed the example, my regex isn't the strongest and I'm more than likely not expressing it well.

Comment: Actually, that was it.   <string>[\S]*.mdb<\/string>  is what I was looking for.  If you want to create an answer, I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your initial example:

```
<string>[\s]*.mdb[\s]*
```

the first [\s]* will not match anything. You perhaps intended:

```
<string>[\S]*.mdb[\s]*
```

But then, I think that the property `Matches` will take in the whole string from start to end, meaning you'll have to put everything, and the dot needs to be escaped since you can call it a wildcard:

```
<string>[\S]*\.mdb[\s]*<\/string>
```

And I think you can remove some unneeded parts (I'm not too familiar with powershell's regex, but I haven't seen any where you have to put character classes written like `\S` within square brackets):

```
<string>\S*\.mdb<\/string>
```

Little explanation:

- `\s` matches a space character, and often also matches a newline, or a tab (`\n` and `\t` respectively).
- `\S` will match everything that `\s` doesn't match.

Comment: ah, didn't know about being able to skip the square brackets.  The regex I ended up going with was '<string>\S*.\.mdb\S*<\/string>'.  Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @Fred Note: `\S` means everything EXCEPT space whereas `\s` means space.  Just to make sure you're clear on what's going on.  Also, that extra `.` will match any character so you might want `\.` instead.

Comment: @ebyrob thanks, I shouldn't have missed that elusive dot, oops!

Comment: @Fred You're welcome. I've just added a small bit of extra explanation I should have added earlier as well.

Comment: ok, so this isn't quite what I'm wanting then.  The goal is to swallow any whitespace before/after the actual string in the tag.

Comment: @Fred I'd recommend: `<string>[^<]*\.mdb\s*<\/string>` or something similar.  It really takes a bit to get comfortable with regex.  I like: http://www.regular-expressions.info/ quite a bit.

Comment: @Fred What do you mean exactly by 'swallow' the whitespace? If you want to match the entire string regardless of the number of trailing spaces around the file path, you might as well simply use `<string>.*?\.mdb\s*<\/string>`. The `.*?` matches everything and anything (except newlines actually) up to `.mdb`, and which I believe is simpler.

Comment: why does .*? match everything and anything except newlines?  I get that .* does 0 or more of everything that . matches, what is the ? doing.

Comment: @Fred The `?` makes the `.*` match as least as possible (called lazy) and without it, it matches as much as possible (called greedy). Compare [this](http://www.regex101.com/r/cR9hA5) with [this](http://www.regex101.com/r/wM0oB8) and you can play around a bit.